# Add text after every line, multiple entries

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I'm just looking for a way to quicken the process of adding info after every line in a notepad application.

I've got a notepad file that has many entries, around 1000+ and am looking to find a way to add ,"" after every line however I can't simply search and replace since every line is different than the other.  Is there another way to simply add three characters after every line reqgardless of what they are?

Comment: Is it a double quote two times you want to add after each line??

Comment: `'^' == Start of line` and `'$' == End of line` while regular expression is checked.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do so by hitting Cntrl+F and then checking regular expression box.And put what you want to replace with what thing. You can put regular expression to find as

```
    \r
```

and replace it with

```
        "YOUR TEXT"\r
```

[image]

Comment: Using \r isn't sufficient to cover all the newline characters.  See [this msdn article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/47af2197-26b4-4b9e-90e8-bfa9d5cd05b4) for more info.

Answer (score 17):

Get a good text editor like [Notepad++](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://notepad-plus-plus.org/&ei=CyLGUJTyO83wrQef34CQDw&usg=AFQjCNH20Y39KL3umNlz40yN398ALm0wKg), then use the Find/Replace box.  Select Regular Expression radio button in the Search Mode section.  Search for `$` (which is the end of line token), and replace with whatever text you'd like.

Comment: This should be the answer. The /r thing did not work even slightly for me

Answer (score 6):

1. place ur mouse at the start of the first line in ur list.
2. Press Alt + "C"
3. A window gets opened. Enter the text that u want to add under "Text to Insert" and press OK.
4. Apply the same procedure for adding text at the end of all the lines.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `\r` by `""\r`, using extended search mode (you may use `\n` instead of `\r` if your file is in UNIX mode).

To add it on a new line after every line, you can replace `\r\n` by `\r\n""\r\n` (or once again `\n` by `\n""\n` depending on your line ending).

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I was working on a delete and Reseed script for SQL Server with 135 tables, so I needed to add the word "Go" on a new line under each script. This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't particular about notepad++ as text editor, try using [Atom](https://atom.io/). It has an option of [multi cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor), through which you can add text to multiple lines effortlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can try the plugin ConyEdit. Use its command line `cc.aal <yourContent>` to append after lines with your content. By the way, it can append different text to each line(push data to an array first, then use the array).

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer didn't work for me on notepad++ on windows, it simply appended the text at the end of the line. Here's what worked:

1. Open search and replace box, in 'find what' field add '$' (meaning the end of line char)
2. In 'replace with' field use, \r - this will add text after each line
3. Click on replace All button to insert the new line.

[image: Check the screenshot of the above steps]